# How to scrape a javascript loaded number from a webpage and save it to clipboard

Tags: c#

im building something like a macro in mine "JitBit Macro Recorder".

I can make some cool stuff there and there is an option to use C# language. I have made a lot of this macro but I'm stuck.

**I need a simple C# script to read a number dynamically loaded by javascript on webpage and save it to clipboard** - that's it.

I can see in the source it's coded like this (there is dynamically loaded number in the place of "-"):

```
<span id="counting">-</span>
```

I hope it's not too much to ask. I know I'm not providing mine own C# code - it's because I don't know this language and it's usually not needed in Macro Recorder but this time it gave me headache.

Greetings!

Comment: I understand your position, but the purpose of this is to help who tried and is  stuck. Try StreamReader to read the page and regular expression to find what you want. If you show me some progress I can help you.

Comment: if can not load the page with StreamReader, try httpWebRequest.

Comment: @PedroSouki well I can show you mine progress in PHP (since this is the language I know the basics of). But after scraping the page with file_get_contents I cant get the number only the "-" since it's dynamically loaded by javascript.

Comment: The text loaded is what you see in `View Source` - which maybe different from what is _rendered_ by the browser _after it has evaluated script_. You can scrape the text returned by the server - it will not include "text" that needs a Javascript engine to evaluate/run the script (which in your example adds some text/content).

Comment: @EdSF so there is no way to read this nymber from webpage/browser? Seems like it looked easier than it is.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this. Javascript only happens in the browser and C# happens in a different process. At least the number is contained in the source code of the page you will not be able to access to it.

You can try with your browser "inspect element" feature since it can access its own memory and it can tell you how the Javascript is being loaded and what variables are there. But to do it with your script you would need to hack into the browser memory address with some kind of debugger. Tricky.

Comment: And there is no way to scrape text from loaded screen? or straight from loaded website in browser?

Comment: The webpage loaded only loads the script. Then the browser updates the number in memory. It is not in the HTML itself.